# Write huge data (4 GB csv file, 4,946,642,530 rows) to a database for analysis, MySql takes for ever

Tags: mysql, csv

Hi I am trying to upload a CSV file that has 7 columns and 4,946,642,530 rows to a my SQL table for data analysis. Its taking forever to upload the file. It took 5 hrs to get to 261897 rows.

Both the DB and the file are on the same machine.

I am to use windows 7 with mysql server 5.6 and I am importing the file via workbench.

Need a faster approach if you could suggest any or suggest an alternative solution for implementing the Data Base so it could up load and handle it faster.

Comment: Did you try the mysql load file command? Do you have any index on the target table?

Comment: i donno why comes python here?

Comment: If it is ok to upload this data to the cloud, you might try [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/what-is-bigquery)

Answer (score 1):

You should better import it via command line

Coming from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html#c5680

`mysqlimport --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=""" --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" --user=YOUR_USERNAME --password YOUR_DATABASE YOUR_TABLE.csv`